# Register abstract class and resolve derived class with Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, service-locator

I have the following code

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract string MethodA();
}

public class B : A
{

    public override string MethodA()
    {
        return "Class B method";
    }
}

public class C : A
{

    public override string MethodA()
    {
        return "Class C method";
    }
}
```

I would like to register and resolve the concrete implementations using service locator. Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, possible, you can register using the name:

```
 var container = new UnityContainer();
 container.RegisterType<A, B>("B");
 container.RegisterType<A, C>("C");
```

And then you can resolve based on the name like below:

```
 A b = container.Resolve<A>("B");
 A C = container.Resolve<A>("C");
```

Answer (score 2):

Given a  unity container container, you should be able to do

```
container.RegisterType<A, B>();
var b = container.Resolve<A>()
```